# LibGDX - TILEDmap - why is layer offset not rendered?

Tags: libgdx, tiled

Rendering a TiledMap is easy in LibGDX, however the layer offsets are not rendered at all but appears correct in TILED (Tiled Map Editor). 
The rendered map appears as all offsets are at 0 (no offsets at all).

Is this feature even supported in Libgdx TiledMap renderer? I've been through the documentation but found no information regarding this.

Thanks very much,
Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Found it.

There are TWO offset properties in TILED, very easy to confuse. 
One is "Layer offset" which just offsets the layer in TILED (no effect when rendering in libgdx).
The second is "Dawing Offset" and can only be reached by going into  "Tileset Properties". This is the one you want.

Changing Drawing Offset will solve the problem and render the offset correctly in LibGDX.

Comment: Layer offset is more recently added than the tile offset feature. Best would be to open an issue about the unsupported layer offset, so that a future version of libgdx may add support for it.